# Error loading component: component, 1 in joomla

Tags: joomla, components

I am getting this errors on my 2 components **com_guru** and **com_easydiscuss** .

```
Error loading component: com_guru, 1
Error loading component: com_easydiscuss, 1
```

There is also a reference to these two component in `#__extensions` table.

What should I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: If you upgraded your joomla version recently- and then errors apperars- so provide us information about changes that you made. I had much the same problems when I was upgrading my site (from 1.5 to 2.5)

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the components from the Joomla backend, check the database to see if there is still any reference to these components and if so, delete the necessary tables or rows. Then reinstall both components and please make sure that your Joomla version is up to date, and that the components are compatible with your Joomla version. I assume that you're using Joomla 2.5

Comment: i try this but nothing happen, i think this is not in only one or two component, this error is showing in all components at front end...have you any idea why this is happens...